# Leaflet Map to PDF using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, export, pdf

I have a geoserver instance providing imagery, hillshade and OSM as WMS services. These tiles are mapped in Leaflet and the user can customize layer order, opacities etc.

I would like to be able to generate large format, high-res PDF from selected map layers and styles. I think this would be best completed server side.

Does anyone have suggestions for a server-side method for rendering pdf's from WMS layers?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html ? What have you tried?

Comment: or you could use QGIS to do it on the desktop

Comment: I had not seen that printing extension @BradHards - I have not tried anything yet and am looking for various methods to render PDFs server-side from WMS